# How to play a custom sound in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I was able to play a simple sound with this line of code:

```
SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);
```

How can I play a customized sound?

Let's say a short mp3

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7482

Comment: I couldn't manage to play the system sound. I get the following message in debug output: "from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0". Any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks for checking out Flutter!

Flutter SDK today (as of May 5, 2017) doesn't have *built-in* support to play and control arbitrary audio. However, we designed our plugin system to support it.

This plugin adds audio support to Flutter: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayer

From the plugin's README:

```
Future play() async {
  final result = await audioPlayer.play(kUrl);
  if (result == 1) setState(() => playerState = PlayerState.playing);
}

// add a isLocal parameter to play a local file
Future playLocal() async {
  final result = await audioPlayer.play(kUrl);
  if (result == 1) setState(() => playerState = PlayerState.playing);
}


Future pause() async {
  final result = await audioPlayer.pause();
  if (result == 1) setState(() => playerState = PlayerState.paused);
}

Future stop() async {
  final result = await audioPlayer.stop();
  if (result == 1) {
    setState(() {
      playerState = PlayerState.stopped;
      position = new Duration();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: No implementation found for method play on channel bz.rxla.flutter/audio)
Any Idea?

Comment: there is no sound. I tried it from my side.

Comment: February 2020 and still no support from Flutter itself. All nice they publish an exotic 'widget of the week' but this is far too basic to not be standard in the library.

Comment: Do we really need a third party plugin to do something as basic as playing an audio clip?!?

Answer (score 55):

Simple solution for playing a file already defined in assets is using AudioCache.
Library: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayers.
[More about AudioCache](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayer/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md)
After adding library to `pubspec.yaml`, import required class:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
```

add an asset in the same file and place the file with sound to assets folder (if you don't have this folder, create it)

```
assets:
- assets/sound_alarm.mp3
```

then add this code:

```
static AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();
const alarmAudioPath = "sound_alarm.mp3";
player.play(alarmAudioPath);
```

An example [here](https://github.com/Yahhi/pomodoro_on_flutter/tree/07e3eaee89c86a93ed187d125d18d2ecd02413dc)

Comment: The library doesn't get imported

Comment: Did you add 
audioplayers: ^0.13.7 
to dependencies in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Yes I did and clicked packages get .But Import statement not detected stating "Target of Uri doesn't exist"

Comment: I was getting the same error . After adding the dependencies and importing the library run the "flutter packages get" command and then close the VS code.This literally solves the error.

Comment: incase if you find the library not importing. type flutter pub get command manually from the terminal. It worked for me

Comment: Consider using this plugin, as it also supports using audio for web, as opposite to other plugins out there. Hence the number of likes and popularity amongst other audio plugins.

Comment: This is not work on flutter web it gives AudioCache not work on web

Answer (score 10):

The audioplayers works (from https://medium.com/@bennett4/adding-custom-sound-effects-to-a-flutter-mobile-app-41594f1f3305):

(1) Add the library to your pubspec.yaml: `audioplayers: ^0.15.1`

(2) In pubspec.yaml under `flutter` add the reference to your assets file:

```
flutter
    assets:
       - assets/yes.mp3
```

MAKE SURE it is under the assets folder. It does not work when it is in a subfolder. For example, something like: - assets/sounds/yes.mp3 will not work. Just put your audio file in the assets folder, not in its subfolder

(3) import the library in your app as: `import package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart;`

(4) then define this function:

```
Future<AudioPlayer> playLocalAsset() async {
    AudioCache cache = new AudioCache();
   //At the next line, DO NOT pass the entire reference such as assets/yes.mp3. This will not work.
   //Just pass the file name only.
    return await cache.play("yes.mp3"); 
}
```

(5) call the function whenever you need to play a sound: `await playLocalAsset();`

Comment: what should we do if we want to stop this audio?

Comment: @DK250  It perfectly works with any sophisticated folder structure like: `assets/sounds/voice/...`.  You should edit your answer.

Answer (score 6):

#### Null-safe code:

1. Add dependency to your `pubspec.yaml` file,

   ```
   dependencies:
     audioplayers: ^0.19.0
   ```
2. Add audio file path to your `pubspec.yaml` file.

   ```
   flutter: 
     assets:
       - assets/audio/my_audio.mp3
   ```
3. Run `flutter pub get`

**Full code:**

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final AudioCache _audioCache = AudioCache(
    prefix: 'audio/',
    fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP),
  );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => _audioCache.play('my_audio.mp3'),
        child: Text('Play Audio'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use just_audio package.

To play sound from a local file...
Follow the steps :-

1. Run flutter pub add just_audio in your terminal
2. import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart'; -> Import package in your file
3. AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();  -> Create the object
4. player.setAsset('path_to_your_audiofile');  -> Set the path to your audio asset
5. player.play(); -> Play the audio

Here is a sample method implementing this :-

```
void playSampleSound() async {
     AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
    await player.setAsset('assets/audio/sample_audio.mp3');
    player.play();
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Answer updated: this approach doesn't work, see comments]
You can use the [video_player](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player/video_player) plugin maintained by the Flutter team. It can reproduce many kinds of media across platforms, including sound files. More specifically, you may want to use the the VideoPlayerController class.

eg.

```
   _controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://www.example.com/soundsFile.wav');
   _controller.play();
```

Comment: OP asked for mp3, does this plugin play that?

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that the fact that this happens to work for some audio files on Android doesn't mean that the plugin supports audio playback. I found out the hard way that this plugin is unable to play audio on iOS. And there is no plan to make it work since that's not the purpose of the `video_player` plugin. The suggested approach in the community is to use `just_audio` by @ryanheise instead.

Comment: @iKeepChangingName Yes, [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) does play mp3 and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

First add

```
dependencies:
  audioplayers: ^5.1.0

flutter:
  assets:
     - assets/
     - assets/icon/
     - assets/sound/
```

Then may i suggest to use a service

```
class AudioService {
    
      AudioService._();
    
      static final AudioService _instance = AudioService._();
    
      factory AudioService() {
        return _instance;
      }
    
      void playSound(AssetSource assetSource) async{
          AudioPlayer().play(assetSource, mode: PlayerMode.lowLatency); // faster play low latency eg for a game...
      }
    }
```

Then use assets as const

```
class Constants{
  static final AssetSource sound = AssetSource('sound/mysound.mp3');
}
```

Finally, the code to call the sound

```
AudioService().playSound(Constants.sound );
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for the 5.2 version of the `audioplayers` plugin:

1. Install the plugin:

```
flutter pub add audioplayers
```

2. Move your files to (in the same root folder of pubspec.yaml)

```
{root}/assets/example.wav
```

3. Add the reference to `pubspec.yaml`

```
  assets:
     - assets/
```

4. Add the code

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
// ...
final player = AudioPlayer();
await player.play(AssetSource('example.wav'));
```

5. If your application is already running, rebuild the app!