# how to add camera captured sound in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
 child: FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade200,
                    // Provide an onPressed callback.
                    onPressed: () async {
                      try {

                        // ...
                        final XFile capturedImage = await _controller.takePicture();
                        // Get the captured image bytes
                        List<int> imageBytes = await capturedImage.readAsBytes();
                        // Modify the image if needed
                        if (_.isGrayScale) {
                          imgLib.Image? originalImage = imgLib.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes));
                          imgLib.Image grayImage = imgLib.grayscale(originalImage!);
                          grayImage = imgLib.copyRotate(grayImage, angle: 0);
                          imageBytes = imgLib.encodePng(grayImage);
                        }
                        // Construct the path where the modified image should be saved
                        final path = join(
                          (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
                          '${DateTime.now()}.png',
                        );
                        // Write the modified image bytes to the file
                        File(path).writeAsBytesSync(imageBytes);
                        // Pass the path to the controller's takepicture method
                        controller.takepicture(path);
                        // ...
                        // await loadCaptureSound();
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    },
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.camera_alt,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
```

I want in this when the image capture from the camera, the capturing sound will produce ,so the users will know that image they are trying to capture are captured from the camera. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813386/how-to-play-a-custom-sound-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Audioplayers library to play the sound when the image is captured.
https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
await player.play(UrlSource('https://example.com/my-audio.wav'));
```

Comment: where i can add this lines of code?

Comment: In the onPressed section

Comment: i want to add sound from asset folder how can i get ?

Comment: You can go through the package documentation.